# Codeigniter group by and create multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've got a function in my model:

```
public function get_job($lsnumber = FALSE) {        
        $this->db->join('administrator', 'job.idadministrator = administrator.idadministrator');
        $this->db->join('artwork', 'job.idjob = artwork.idjob');

        if($lsnumber === FALSE) {
            $query = $this->db->get('job');
            return $query->result_array();
        }
    }
```

Returning this lets me generate a row for each entry in the database using a foreach loop in my view.

Sometimes these rows will have things in common, for example the `idjob` field as referenced in the `join` rule.

At the moment, I'm getting an output (from `print_r`) like this:

```
Array
(
    [idjob] => 1
    [lsnumber] => 12345
    [custname] => Scott Brown (Customer)
    [custemail] => sbrown@example.com
    [custcompany] => Customer
    [idadministrator] => 1
    [complete] => 0
    [administratorname] => Scott Brown (Administrator)
    [administratoremail] => scott@example.com
    [administratorjob] => Job
    [administratorphone] => 01234 567890
    [idartwork] => 1
    [filename] => gb-usb1.jpg
    [productname] => Bespoke USB Drive
    [revision] => 0
    [status] => N
)

Array
(
    [idjob] => 1
    [lsnumber] => 12345
    [custname] => Scott Brown (Customer)
    [custemail] => sbrown@example.com
    [custcompany] => LSi (Customer)
    [idadministrator] => 1
    [complete] => 0
    [administratorname] => Scott Brown (Administrator)
    [administratoremail] => scott@example.com
    [administratorjob] => Job
    [administratorphone] => 01234 567890
    [idartwork] => 2
    [filename] => pa17.jpg
    [productname] => Notebooks
    [revision] => 0
    [status] => Y
)
```

However, I'd like the array to be grouped and multidimensional, something like this:

```
Array
(
    [idjob] => 1
    [lsnumber] => 12345
    [custname] => Scott Brown (Customer)
    [custemail] => sbrown@example.com
    [custcompany] => Customer
    [idadministrator] => 1
    [complete] => 0
    [administratorname] => Scott Brown (Administrator)
    [administratoremail] => scott@example.com
    [administratorjob] => Job
    [administratorphone] => 01234 567890
    [artwork][0] => Array
        (   
            [idartwork] => 1
            [filename] => gb-usb1.jpg
            [productname] => Bespoke USB Drive
            [revision] => 0
            [status] => N
        )
    [artwork][1] => Array
        (   
            [idartwork] => 2
            [filename] => pa17.jpg
            [productname] => Notebooks
            [revision] => 0
            [status] => Y
        )
)
```

I want to be able to group it by the `idjob` and build a sub-array of all the `artwork`s joined to it.

I've tried all kinds of thing: `array_chunk()`, group by, all sorts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this, you may have to change it slightly:

```
function get_job(){
    $data   = array();
    $data   = $this->db->get('job')->result_array();
    foreach( $data as $key=>$each ){
        $data[$key]              = $this->db->where('idadministrator', $each['idadministrator'])->get('administrator')->row_array();
        $data[$key]['artwork']   = $this->db->where('idjob', $each['idjob'])->get('artwork')->result_array();  
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. One more thing though, how can I tweak it to keep the `idjob`, `custname` etc in the array?

Comment: Don't worry, I've figured that out. Changed the first `$data[$key]` to the job information and added another `$key` for `administrator`. Thanks for your help and, what's better, it almost all makes sense to me :)

Comment: Bad idea. You run a query for each job. Now consider one query takes 1ms and there are 10000 jobs => your page needs 10 seconds to load. Your application is not very scalable (= performance tremendously depends on the amount of data). With the join-approach you have a single query being executed