# Codeigniter gettiing one to many relation from model and parsing in view

Tags: database, codeigniter, model

I have 3 tables namely - `celebs`, `celeb_roles`, `celeb_industry`.
`celebs` is the main table with one to many relation with other 2 tables.

`celebs` is having the columns - 
id, name, nationality, status.

`celebs_roles` is having the columns - 
id, celeb_id, role_id.

`celebs_industry` is having the columns - 
id, celeb_id, industry_id.

There are limited and fixed number of roles and industry. So I have put them in a config file with `id=>value` pair. So if I get `role_id` from result, I can take the value from the config file. Same goes for `industry_id`.

Now for getting a celeb details from one given id, I have written the query like below in model.

```
public function getCelebSingle($celebId)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('celebs');
    $this->db->join('celebs_roles', 'celebs_roles.celeb_id = celebs.id');
    $this->db->join('celebs_industry', 'celebs_industry.celeb_id = celebs.id');
    $this->db->where('celebs_roles.celeb_id', $celebId);
    $this->db->where('celebs_industry.celeb_id', $celebId);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

In the database there is one record in `celebs`, with that same celeb_id having 2 records in each of other 2 tables. 
The result I got is below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => new test
        [nationality] =>  whatever
        [status] => Pending
        [celeb_id] => 1
        [role_id] => 1
        [industry_id] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => new test
        [nationality] =>  whatever
        [status] => Pending
        [celeb_id] => 1
        [role_id] => 3
        [industry_id] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => new test
        [nationality] =>  whatever
        [status] => Pending 
        [celeb_id] => 1
        [role_id] => 1
        [industry_id] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => new test
        [nationality] =>  whatever
        [status] => Pending
        [celeb_id] => 1
        [role_id] => 3
        [industry_id] => 2
    )
)
```

So for only one record of `celebs` table, I need to put this in a loop, which I think is a bit of overload. If number of records increase in other 2 tables, then the items in the result array also will increase. So I wonder, can I get the result something like below ?

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => new test
        [nationality] =>  whatever
        [status] => Pending
        [celeb_roles] => array(
                                [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [celeb_id] => 1
                                    [role_id] =>  1
                                )
                                [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [celeb_id] => 1
                                    [role_id] =>  2
                                )
                        )
        [celeb_industry] => array(
                                [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [celeb_id] => 1
                                    [industry_id] =>  1
                                )
                                [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [celeb_id] => 1
                                    [industry_id] =>  2
                                )
                        )
    )
)
```

This is just an expectation from the result array, but I don't know how to achieve this resultant array. Can someone have a look at it?

Here is a possible duplicate - [Codeigniter group by and create multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745345/codeigniter-group-by-and-create-multidimensional-array) . But the answer is NOT really satisfying. The answers clearly states not to use JOIN, but to use normal Codeigniter get query which I think will result in 3 queries for the question. What if I select all records of `celebs` table ? Then, the number of queries will be `3 * Number of records in celebs table` , which will overload.  If there is no other way, I have to do it this way only, but I hope there will be better ways to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745345/codeigniter-group-by-and-create-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 2):

Please do this, i am not sure this is right but you need to try this way if you want to result as you had declared in expectation array.

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('celebs');
    $this->db->join('celebs_roles', 'celebs_roles.celeb_id = celebs.id');
    $this->db->join('celebs_industry', 'celebs_industry.celeb_id = celebs.id');
    $this->db->where('celebs_roles.celeb_id', $celebId);
    $this->db->where('celebs_industry.celeb_id', $celebId);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $new_array = array();
    foreach ($result as $key => $value){
        $new_array = $value;
            foreach ($result as $key1 => $value1){
                $new_array['celeb_roles'][$key1]['id'] = $value1['id'];
                $new_array['celeb_roles'][$key1]['celeb_id'] = $value1['celeb_id'];
                $new_array['celeb_roles'][$key1]['role_id'] = $value1['role_id'];
            }

    }
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I have tried this. Now celeb_roles are showing in an array after a bit of modification, but instead of 2 celeb_roles, I am getting 4, as there are 2 celeb roles, and 2 industry.  But  I think I can use array_unique  and get the required results.  But a big Thanks to you for showing the way.